# C type cast for typedef defined in preprocessor block

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, typedef

I am trying to fix this compiler warning:

```
warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'myRealVar', possible loss of data
```

myRealVar is defined in a preprocessor block:

```
#ifdef SINGLE_PRECISION
typedef float myRealVar;
#else
typedef double myRealVar;
#endif
```

The warning occurs on the line that basically looks like this:

```
someVar[a][b] = 1.0/sqrt(someVar[a][b]);
```

I have tried C-style type casting: (myRealVar) but this doesn't seem to resolve the warning. How should I properly resolve this issue?

**Edit:**
This did the trick. Thanks Weather Vane and Olaf. Not sure why my previous attempts at C-casting didn't working.

```
someVar[a][b] = (myRealVar)(1.0/sqrt(someVar[a][b]));
```

Comment: What was the C-style cast you tried?  Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40244753/edit) to add it?

Comment: `1.0` has the type `double`.

Comment: "I have tried C-style type casting: (myRealVar) but this doesn't seem to resolve the warning" - I don't see that cast. Where is your [mcve]?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what reason do you have for using `float`? IMHO, `double` is the preferred type in 99.99% of cases anyway

Comment: If greater precision is not a priority and you're developing a large system, using a float instead of double cuts down memory overhead since floats are 4 bytes and doubles are 8 bytes according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast the `1.0` as well as the return value from `sqrt`, to remove the warning. Both have the type `double`.

```
someVar[a][b] = (myRealVar)1.0 / (myRealVar)sqrt(someVar[a][b]);
```

Comment: Why not leave the division as `double` and just cast the result? It is good practice to perform all intermediate calculations in higher precision.